# Соединить домен ссылки с ссылкой товара

Tags: python, парсер

Как правильно соединить домен ссылки + карточку товара?
вот пример правильной карточки с товаром:

```
https://www.sunnytoy.ru/shop/kidkraft_kukoljnyj_domik_kidkraft_kajli_kaylee_kajla_kayla_2.html
```

У меня получается

```
/shop/kidkraft_kukoljnyj_domik_kidkraft_kajli_kaylee_kajla_kayla_2.htmlhttps://www.sunnytoy.ru/
```

когда меняю местами код перед get("href) получается ошибка. В парсинге новичок. Ответ на свой вопрос в свободном доступе не нашел. Пишу сюда.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers={'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101  Firefox/121.0"}

link=("https://www.sunnytoy.ru/shop/25/")
responce=requests .get(link,headers=headers).text
bs=BeautifulSoup(responce,'lxml')

name_doma=bs.find_all('span',{'itemprop':'name'})[3:]
price_doma=bs.find_all('div',class_='price')[1:]
valuta_doma=bs.find_all('div',class_='otz')
card_url=bs.find_all("a",itemprop="url")

nd=[]
prd=[]
zd=[]
li=[]
for z,v,i,l in zip(name_doma, price_doma,valuta_doma,card_url):
nd.append(z.getText())
prd.append(v.getText())
zd.append(i.getText())
li.append(l.get('href'))
print(z.getText(),v.getText(),i.getText(),l.get("href")+("https://www.sunnytoy.ru/"))**#Проблема Тут**




exel=pd.DataFrame()
exel['Название Товара']=nd
exel['Цена']=prd
exel['Отзывы к Товару']=zd
exel['Сылка Товара']=li
exel.to_excel('./Парсинг_Домов.xlsx',index=False)
```

Comment: у вас на самом деле ни одного отступа в коде?